# Swizzling in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swizzling

If we a new enhancement project within which we need to integrate FCM notifications we need to know swizzling is enabled or enabled .
How to know swizzling method is enabled or disabled in our project?

Comment: Please check my answer @UseriOSDev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your info.plist file.

Please check key `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` is set to NO then method swizzling is disabled.

If you have disabled swizzling by setting `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to NO in your app's Info.plist, you should manually set the APNS token in your application delegate's `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method if you would like to set the type of the APNS token.